# Confusion in Sigma and Standard deviation

Tags: lean, 6-sigma

I am tryin to understand relation between Six Sigma and Standard Deviation. What I understand is Standard deviation means variability in something. Higher standard deviation means data is more spread out and not centered around central tendency or mean in normal distribution.

Then why 6 sigma which means 6 standard deviation from mean leads to a more defect free process? I have read that +-6 SD within USL and LSL are ideal but does it not mean there is more variation which Six Sigma methodology aims to reduce?

Comment: *I have read that +-6 SD within USL and LSL are ideal but does it not mean there is more variation which Six Sigma methodology aims to reduce?* Are you asking why stop optimizing when you still have movement of -6/+6 standard deviations within the USL and LSL?

Answer (score 0):

The term "six sigma" considers a **ratio**. In the numerator we have the "tolerance range" (= upper specification limit - lower specification limit) and in the denominator the standard deviation Sd[process]. The larger this ratio, the more certain are we that the product is within the tolerance range.

Consider the following picture:

[image]

If the upper and lower specification reads +/3, then our scrap rate is approx. 2700ppm. However, if the specification limits read +/-6, then our scrap rate is only approx. 0.002ppm. Thus, the larger the ratio, the further away are the specification limits (expressed in terms of the standard deviation).

In my opinion these calculations -- although mathematically correct -- are misleading. Real processes are never perfectly centered, and never perfectly normal. Making predictions about the tail of a distribution, which we are not able to sample during our study, is a sure way to failure, because we rely on assumptions, which are probably wrong.